# Selecting Android Spinner Causes WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android, exception, spinner

I created a custom AlertDialog to display a Spinner and some EditText elements. When I select a menu option, this custom AlertDialog gets launched. Everything works fine until I actually select the spinner to try and select an item, at which point I get the BadTokenException. I've read other StackOverflow posts saying that similiar exceptions were the result of trying to display a diaglog using getApplicationContext() rather than passing Activity.this. I'm not explicitly passing getApplicationContext() to anything related to this AlertDialog.

To setup this custom AlertDiaglog, I created a layout file containing the Spinner and EditText elements, and then made the AlertDialog use that layout:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplication().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.custom_layout_root));
spinner = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_layout_spinner);
ArrayAdapter adap = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Activity.this, R.array.data, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adap);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerItemListener());

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Title");
dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new Dialog.OnClickListener() ...
...
dialog.show();
```

This code all works fine for displaying the AlertDialog. However, when I actually touch the Spinner, I get the following problem:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException)) 
ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1704
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4203
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 791
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 549
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Does anyone have an idea  of what's going on? The exception message says:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

I believe this is the message others have seen for this type of problem, so I'm assuming that ApplicationContext is somewhere in the mix, but I'm not sure where. My manifest is setup with minSdk of 1.5 with a Target SDK of 1.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've read other StackOverflow posts saying that similiar exceptions were the result of trying to display a diaglog using getApplicationContext() rather than passing Activity.this.
>   I'm not explicitly passing getApplicationContext() to anything related to this AlertDialog.

Presumably this line of code actually **is** doing just that — you're asking the **`Application`** to use its context to access a service, rather than that of the current **`Window`**:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
  (LayoutInflater) getApplication().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Can't you just replace that with the version below, since you're launching the `AlertDialog` from an `Activity`?

```
LayoutInflater inflater =
  (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Or even simpler:

`LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();`

Comment: Christopher, thanks a lot! Using getLayoutInflater() by itself did the trick. From the other posts I read, I think I just completely focused on what was being passed to the AlertDialog, and didn't even pay attention to the LayoutInflater. Thanks again!

Comment: wow thank you! thats working, but i dont understand why everything works fine except new Alertdialogs.

Answer (score 2):

I lost a lot of time with this strange problem, but in the end I solved as follows. Look this code:

```
/**
 * Initializes the body of the screen that serves a user to edit a new question.
 */
private void onStart_initializeNewQuestion()
{
    /**
     * 0. Local variables.
     */
    Spinner spinner, spinner2;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter;
    EditText editText;

    /**
     * 1. Inflate the layout, and configure useful pointers.
     */
    this.viewGroup_body_newquestion= (ViewGroup) this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_survey_newquestion, null);

    /**
     * 2. Populate the spinner with user choices, and then set responding spinner to user selections
     */
    spinner= (Spinner) this.viewGroup_body_newquestion.findViewById(R.id.create_survey_newquestion_spinner_questionType);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    arrayAdapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.create_surveys_newquestion_spinnerOptions,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    // spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
        {
            String choice;
            choice= parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            U.e(U.VERBOSE, "CreateSurveyActivity.onStart_initializeNewQuestion(listener@spinner_questionType): " + choice);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spinner2= new Spinner(this);
    spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
        {
            String choice;
            choice= parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            U.e(U.VERBOSE, "CreateSurveyActivity.onStart_initializeNewQuestion(listener@spinner_questionType): " + choice);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) this.viewGroup_body_newquestion.getChildAt(0);
    linearLayout.addView(spinner2);


}
```

Look spinner vs spinner2: spinner exists inside an inflated layout (whose root is a ScrollView) and spinner2 is created programatically on this, which is an Activity object.

As I cannot change the spinner1 context to coincide with this context, finally I created a new Spinner directly on this context. And so spinner does not works while spinner2 it works.

PS: The layout inflater used is the same used to inflate a lot of other layouts:

```
    this.layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**PS2: the solution provided by Christopher allows to keep using the original spinner, so it is a better solution! :)**